# Parse error When i setup site in Wampserver

Tags: magento

When I Setup Site in Wampserver that is my localhost it gives error

Parse error: parse error in D:\wamp\www\microcad\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\2columns-left.phtml on line 98

Please Help Me.Thanks

Here is my Code of 2column-left.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Template for Mage_Page_Block_Html
 */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
    <div class="page">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        <div class="main-container col2-left-layout">
            <div class="main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                <div class="col-main">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-left sidebar">
                    <?php if (Mage::registry('current_category')) { ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
                    <? }else{?>
                    <div class="block block-layered-nav">
                        <div class="block-title"><strong><span>Shop By</span></strong></div>
                        <div class="block-content">
                        <p class="block-subtitle">Signage Showroom</p>
                        <dl id="narrow-by-list">
                            <dd class="last odd">
                            <ol>
                              <?php
                              $parentid=2; // parent id which you want sub category
                              $categories=explode(',',Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentid)->getChildren());
                              $n = count($categories);
                              $left_cat=1;
                              foreach($categories as $cat){ 
                                if(left_cat==$n){
                                    $last_cat='last';
                                }else{
                                    $last_cat='';
                                }
                                $left_cat++;
                                 $category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat);
                              ?>

                               <li class="<?php echo $last_cat;?>"><a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl();?>"><?php echo $category->getName();?></a></li>
                            <?php } ?>


                            </ol>
                            </dd>                           
                        </dl>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
                    <? }?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can u show 2columns-left.phtml ?

Comment: I think this `if(left_cat==$n){` should be `if($left_cat==$n){` and make sure all the curly brackets are properly closed. And don't use short tags `<? `. Replace them all by `<?php `